# Error when trying to run a program that creates a Java DataBase. What am I missing?

Tags: java, database, derby, javadb

This is a sample program from my book, I need to run this before I run my own assignment program to access the database and retrieve data. My problem is, this code doesn't run normally, it gives me:

```
"ERROR: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:CityDB;create=true" 

at runtime.
```

I am using IntelliJ 13 - Community Edition.

```
import java.sql.*;

/**
This program creates the CityDB database.                                    *
*/

public class CreateCityDB {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String sql;
    final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby:CityDB;create=true";

    try {
        // Create a connection to the database.
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);

        // Create a Statement object.
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        // Create the Dvd table.
        System.out.println("Creating the City table...");
        stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE City ("    +
                    "CityName CHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "   +
                    "Population DOUBLE)");

        // Add some rows to the new table.
        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
                "('Beijing', 12500000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Buenos Aires', 13170000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Cairo', 14450000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Calcutta', 15100000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Delhi', 18680000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Jakarta', 18900000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Karachi', 11800000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Lagos', 13488000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('London', 12875000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Los Angeles', 15250000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Manila', 16300000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Mexico City', 20450000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Moscow', 15000000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Mumbai', 19200000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('New York City', 19750000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Osaka', 17350000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Sao Paulo', 18850000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Seoul', 20550000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Shanghai', 16650000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql = "INSERT INTO City VALUES" +
        "('Tokyo', 32450000)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        // Close Resources
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: No suitable driver found. It means that the JDBC driver of Derby is not in the runtime classpath. Add it to the classpath.

Comment: @JBNizet I have Path and CLASSPATH setup correctly.

Comment: @EdoIsa your question is confusing,your code shows that you are using derby database but tag is mysql.Which database are you using exactly?

Comment: I am using Derby ... I havn't gone past this error to ACTUALLY use any database, to be exact. I am just confused on the setup.

Comment: Isn't it a bit overkill to do this with a Java program? Does derby not accept SQL scripts?

Comment: I dont know man, just one of my college assignments from a book, and I havn't even started because I cant get this database set up.  :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the class first using:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
```

**Edit:**

Turns out JavaDB is not readily available in the JDK. See http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/derby_app.html#Changing+the+application+to+use+the+Derby+Embedded+Driver.

> To use Derby in its embedded mode set your CLASSPATH to include the jar files listed below:
>   derby.jar: contains the Derby engine and the Derby Embedded JDBC driver

**Edit 2:**

I've tried compiling your example with only `derby.jar` on the classpath and it fails. After adding `derbyclient.jar` too it works (from JDK7).

Comment: This line goes in main method correct? I put it as the 1st line and I am getting a huge error coming from that line.

Comment: Yes I have set my CLASSPATH. It currently holds:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\db\lib\derby.jar;

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\db\lib\derbytools.jar;

Comment: I've tried it in a new project, and turns out you also need derbyclient.jar.

Comment: Ya I figured, I just added that too. Still getting the error, because I dont know where to place: 

"Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");

Comment: With Class.forName  inserted after "String sql;", I am getting an error:  **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver

// lots of errors
//
//
//

at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at CH_16.CreateCityDB.main(CreateCityDB.java:12)** ---- that line 12 its referring to, is where I put "Class.forName"

Comment: Then your classpath is not configured correctly. In IntelliJ you need to right click your project - choose "Open Module Settings", then go to *libraries* and add derby.jar and derbyclient.jar.

Answer (score 2):

No suitable driver means you are not adding the required jar in your class path.
If you are using eclipse then follow this

- right click on project
- click build path->configure build path
- then click libraries tab
- Then click add external jar and give the path of the jar file.
- Re run the project

Follow the steps for IntelliJ IDEA

1. Click File
2. Click Project Structure(short cut ctrl + shift + alt + s)
3. Then click module then on dependencies
4. Then click on  add->project library

Comment: I am not using Eclipse, can you describe what this does so I can try to figure it out in IntelliJ?

Comment: @EdoIsa which database are you using?

Comment: I am using JavaDB, Derby i think it was. The code I posted up there ... its from my book, and its using Derby.

Comment: What do I click from here and which directory should I choose?

http://postimg.org/image/vnji07hfv/

Comment: @MatthijsBierman YES! That part is in the book, but doesn't say how!